# Help for understanding this random variable derivation

Tags: probability

I can't decypher how the author comes to this solution, here is the problem

> The cost of manufacturing a certain book is **\$3** per book up to
>   **1000** copies, **\$2** per copy between **1000** and **5000** copies, and **\$1** per copy afterwards. In reality of course books
>   are printed in round lots and not on demand "as you go." What we
>   assume here is tantamount to selling all overstock at cost, with no
>   loss of business due to understock. Suppose we print **1000** copies
>   initially and price the book at **$5**. Let X be the number of copies
>   that will be sold. It should evident that once **X** is known, we can
>   compute the profit or loss from the sales, call this **Y**. The
>   formula connecting **Y** with **X** is given below

[image]

I dont understand the derivations to come out with this random variable **Y**, if anybody can provide me a step by step, I will very gracefuly.

Comment: I am puzzled by the phrase "Suppose we print $1000$ copies initially".  I don't think they mean that.  I think they mean "Suppose we print a very large number of copies initially".  After all, there is no penalty for over production.  Was that your question?

Comment: On re-reading the calculation is also unclear.  To get the first line in the definition of $Y$ they assume that you are out the $\$3000$ no matter what, which appears to contradict their claim that I can always sell overstock at cost.  I can make something up that matches the formulas they give...but I do think the problem is very poorly phrased.

Comment: To make something up:  Assume that you must pay $\$3000$ for the initial run of $1000$ copies and that this money can only be made back by market price sales (so if $X=0$ you are out $\$3000$).  Then assume that you print many more copies (according to the pricing schedule) but this cost can be recouped by selling any overstock.  I believe that these assumptions match their table.

Comment: Here, you can see the book with the problem: https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=JUUGCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=The+cost+of+manufacturing+a+certain+book+is+$3+per+book+up+to+1000+copies,+$2+per+copy+between+1000+and+5000+copies,+and+1+per+copy+afterwards.+In&source=bl&ots=zmK9UIQV6K&sig=qO3yvzWuXVffqi_6hK_X2wGc6pY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1-aeqi4PNAhUDiJAKHduYDBgQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: That link doesn't appear to work, but I expect you have reproduced the problem faithfully.  I think the scheme I made up makes sense and it does match the answer.  I note that the posted solution of @callculus follows this scheme as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First interval**

The revenue for $0$ to $1000$ books is $5\cdot X$. The costs are $3\cdot 1000=3000 $ because $1000$ books has to be printed at most. Thus the profit function for the first interval is $5\cdot X-3000 \quad \texttt{if} \ \ X\leq 1000$

**Second interval**

To evaluate the profit for the second interval we have first to calculate the profit at $X=1000$ (upper limit of first interval): $5\cdot 1000-3000=2000$.
Every additional book above $X=1000$ has a cost of $2$ and a selling price of $5$. Therefore the profit for each book is $3(=5-2)$.

From the $1001st$ to the $5000th$ book each book creates 3 dollars additional profit. If we have, for instance, $1001$ books in total $1000$ books have to be substracted because they have been regarded in the cost of the upper bound of the first interval, which is $2000$. The profit function for the interval from 1001 to 5000 becomes

$2000+3\cdot (X-1000) \quad \texttt{if} \ \ 1000<  X\leq 5000$

**Third interval**

Now we have to calculate the profit of $5000$ books. This is $2000+3\cdot (5000-1000)=14000$. The cost for each book is $1$ dollar. Thus the profit for one book is $4(=5-1)$ dollars. And again we subtract the amount of books which has been regarded in the previous intervals. We substract $5000$ books. The profit function for the third interval is

$14000+4\cdot (X-5000) \quad \texttt{if} \ \ X> 5000$

Comment: amazing amazing, thanks so much for so nice and neat explanation, callculus!!

Comment: Nice that it helps. You´re welcome.